# Return the middle node of a linked list without cloning

Tags: algorithm, rust, linked-list

There is a [known problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/middle-of-the-linked-list/) of search of the middle node of a linked list:

> Given a non-empty, singly linked list with head node `head`, return a middle node of linked list.
> If there are two middle nodes, return the second middle node.

Here is my solution:

```
pub fn middle_node(head: Option<Box<ListNode>>) -> Option<Box<ListNode>> {
    if head.is_none() { return None; }
    let mut slow = &head;
    let mut fast = &head;
    while fast.is_some() && fast.as_ref().unwrap().next.is_some() {
        fast = &fast.as_ref().unwrap().next.as_ref().unwrap().next;
        slow = &slow.as_ref().unwrap().next;
    }
    slow.clone()
}
```

The problem is that I copy the half of the list by calling `slow.clone()`, where slow is pointing at the middle node. I have to clone it because the result has type of `Option<Box<ListNode>>`, not `&Option<Box<ListNode>>`. I cannot change the function signature - it is given by Leetcode.
Rust does not allow to move values from the list while I have another reference to one of its nodes.

Is there a way to return the middle node without copying the half of the list?

Comment: Given that you cannot edit the method signature, you have to use `clone()` one way or the other

Comment: LeetCode is trash precisely because it makes you jump through weird hoops. Whoever translated this (and most of their Rust problems) from whatever other language does not appear to have done any research on how to actually write Rust. The 2-pointer approach *can* be done in safe Rust, but it can't be done with this API. You'll need to clone (or use `unsafe`, but that's more effort than this exercise deserves).

Comment: @trentcl I agree, I recommend using Codeforces to practice Rust, in Codeforces we write a full program and deal input, output ourselves, other than implementing one function with the specified signature.

Comment: @trentcl Thanks for the comment! What would be a good API for the 2-pointer approach? Pass and return references instead of moving original values?

Comment: Without changing `ListNode`, `fn middle_node(head: Option<&ListNode>) -> Option<&ListNode>` should be implementable (note: `Option::as_deref` may come in handy for the implementation). If this is interesting to you, I recommend [Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/).

Comment: @trentcl How can I avoid cloning using unsafe Rust?

Comment: @EvgeniNabokov I'm not sure whether you actually can or not. The idea would be to turn each `Box<ListNode>` into a `*mut ListNode` as you encounter it so you never have an aliased `Box`. But this data structure was not designed for iterating in this way. Chapter 6 of *Too Many Linked Lists* describes a singly linked list that supports this algorithm natively because it uses raw pointers for the links. I recommend using that definition instead of LeetCode's if you want to try to implement it without cloning.